# Is it ok if a URN leads me to a 404?

Tags: http-status-code-404, urn

Is it ok if a URN leads me to a 404?

A URN that leads to a 404 is valid? May it be used for describing XML files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s okay. Actually, that’s the point of URNs: they are "location independent":

> Uniform Resource Names (URNs) are resource identifiers with the specific requirements for enabling location independent identification of a resource, as well as longevity of reference.

(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3406#section-1.0)

URNs *identify*. E.g. `urn:isbn:0451450523` represents the book with the ISBN 0451450523. That’s it. No (canonical) web page etc. The corresponding specification of this `isbn` namespace would be https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3187.

(Of course you could use client-side resolvers, e.g. browser add-ons, that "do something" when encountering URNs.)

---

> may it be used for describing XML files?

Note that you can’t just start minting URN namespaces. You need to register them. You can find all registered URN namespaces there: **http://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces**

Now, if there is an appropriate URN namespace for your use case you could use such URNs, if you follow the specification of that particular namespace.

(For "for use within internal or limited experimental contexts" you could mint URN namespaces [starting with `X-`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3406#section-3.1) without registration.)